# How can i add superscript to asp.net button control?

Tags: asp.net, formatting, aspbutton

I have an asp.net button control used inside ajax AccordionPane and i want to apply the superscipt to the text of button  such as "Button1 <sup>*Demo</sup> ".How can i do this?

Comment: How would you do it in plain HTML?

Comment: i don't have any idea please provide me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style it just as you would normal HTML/CSS:

```
<button ID="btn" runat="server">Button 1 <sup>*Demo</sup></button>
```

Comment: now if i use this onclick function of this button won't rediect to any other page.In fact its onclick event does not get fired